# MS SQL Server Zero Padding

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

**EDIT:**
**I'm changing column datatype to Varchar, should suggestion work, answer will be upvoted**

Full Story:
I receive data for a person with an associated temporary number for every person that is 5 digits long, I process this information and then send variables to a stored procedure that handles the inserting of this data. When sending the variables to the stored procedure I appear to be losing any prefixed 0's.
For example:
Number sent to stored Proc - Number actually inserted column

```
12345 - 12345  
01234 - 1234  
12340 - 12340
```

This only appears to be happening for numbers with a `0` in front. Meaning if I received:
`00012` it would insert as `12`

Is there a way where I could either update the column to always `0` pad to the left by a fixed number, meaning if we got `12` it would automatically make the value `00012`.
OR
Is there a way to do this with the variable when its received by the stored procedure before the variable is inserted into the table. 
Something along the lines of:

```
SET @zeroPaddedFixedNum = LeftPad(@numberRecieved, '0', 5);
```

Additionally, I now need to stop any more numbers from inserting and update all current incorrectly lengthed numbers. Any suggestions?

Perhaps it's just my Google ability that has failed but I have tried searching numerous pages.

Comment: What is the type of the column you're inserting into? Sounds like your stored proc is expecting an `INT` and you're sending it a `VARCHAR` which is being implicitly converted. A `VARCHAR` value of `'01234'` converts to an `INT` of `1234`. Could you post the code for your stored proc and your call to it with some example input values?

Comment: That's a start, thank you very much for your reply. The number is captured as a string and sent through to the stored procedure. The stored procedure was indeed expecting an int value. The column itself is also an int value. Do you think updating the column to a varchar, and updating the stored proc variable to varchar would solve the problem? I can add the insert statement if needed.

Comment: Yes, if you wish to store values like `01234`, you cannot use an `INT` type. Change the column to a `VARCHAR(5)` and do the `INSERT` as per [Madhivanan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/358538/madhivanan)'s answer below.

Comment: @3N1GM4 But - **if these values *are* numbers** - one should not change the type because I need a special format for one special SP. Rather do the padding on the fly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, the column should be of varchar datatype. You can then do this

```
Insert into table(col)
select right('00000'+cast(@var as varchar(5)),5)
```

EDIT : To update existing data

```
Update table
set col=right('00000'+cast(col as varchar(5)),5)
where len(col)<5
```

Comment: This is a dangerous approach! Just imagine a number exceeding 5 digits. It will be truncated without complaints...

Comment: yes but OP wants to format it for 5 digits so my understanding is that it wont exceed 5 in length :)

Comment: This padding approach is something you'll find very often here on SO. People learn: *Ah, that's the way how to pad a string!* and run into darkness... There are much better ways, in this case (SS2012) it is `FORMAT()`

Comment: I understand the concern of this number possibly being higher than 5 digits but the way the numbers are generated and sent to me they start at 00000 until 99999 and then start at 0 again so it will never be greater than 5 digits. Madhivanan, I have updated the column to a varchar and stored proc to varchar. My last question do you possibly know how to update all current numbers that are less than 5 digits to zero pad LEFT? So the values that are currently:
12
4123
582
to be:
00012
04123
00582

Comment: Yes I agree. That is one of the methods that works in all versions :)

Comment: @Madhivanan Thank you so much for your time. Correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, you'll have to use `VARCHAR(5)` for your needs... But I would not change the columns type, if the values stored are numbers actually. Rather use one of the following, whenever you pass these values to your SP (You might use a computed column or a `VIEW` though).

Try

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(YourNumber,5),' ','0');
```

The big advantage: In cases, where your number exceeds 5 digits, this would return `*****`. It is better to get an error than to get wrong numbers... Other approaches with `RIGHT()` might truncate your result unpredictably.

With SQL Server 2012 you should use `FORMAT()`

```
SELECT FORMAT(YourNumber,'00000')
```

Comment: Format option is great

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you for your time and effort in answering, and I will upvote it. I actually do agree with your logic in your answer however as mentioned in a reply "I understand the concern of this number possibly being higher than 5 digits but the way the numbers are generated and sent to me they start at 00000 until 99999 and then start at 0 again so it will never be greater than 5 digits." And had this been the first answer I also would have taken it. However, if I am receiving a variable of varchar or int and I'm inserting it. How would the select statement work?

Comment: @Jarryd just include `FORMAT` to your insert statement: `INSERT INTO SomeTbl(col1,col2,...) SELECT FORMAT(YourNumber,5), OtherColumn, ... FROM SomeWhere`. **Data types are very important!** If these are numbers, you should have a good reason not to treat them as numbers...

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server 2012, so `FORMAT()` is the right solution.